# Can I use the variable given in my dataset to create a new variable?

Tags: r, classification, feature-selection

Background: I have a data set that has lot of missing values so for each observation i would like to give a score on how many field's the person has input, my hypothesis is that higher the no of fields he inputs, higher is his chance of getting converted.

I'm trying to build a scoring model. I have around 10 variables in my dataset. My question is: if for an observation/record, let's say I have 4 missing values, so can I use the remaining 6 for calculating the score and input that as a feature in my model. Would this be redundant?

Comment: what do you mean by "getting converted"?

Comment: @Qaswed: It means that he would convert into a lead or not.

Comment: And what do you mean by "lead"? Can you give more detail about your data and your model?

Comment: @Qaswed The context is that of a classification i.e. cusomter would end up buying your product or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you try the following

```
tmp <- runif(1000) # generate random vales
tmp[sample(1:1000, size = 100, replace = FALSE)] <- NA # generate some NAs

X <- matrix(tmp, ncol = 10) # make tmp a 100 x 10 matrix 

score <- apply(X, 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))) # get the score (number of complete covariates)

y <- sample(c(0, 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE) # generate binary y

mod <- glm(y ~ X + score, family = binomial(link = "logit")) # estimate a logistic regression

round(coef(mod), digits = 2) # gives

#(Intercept)     X1     X2    X3     X4     X5     X6     X7     X8     X9     X10  score 
#       2.74  -1.92  -1.36  0.24   0.45  -1.22   0.75  -3.84  -0.10   0.03    0.62     NA
```

If you think about it is clear that the coefficient of `score` has to be `NA`: in the regression only complete observations are used; and this means that only observations with a score of `10`. So `score` is a constant varible in the regression model without any explanation. This changes of course if you can drop (non relevant) variables (eg):

```
glm(y ~ X[, c(1, 4:6, 9)] + score, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Comment: @let me get back to you on this one!